# CakePHP Refresh specific user session after updating details

Tags: session, cakephp

I want to refresh the session of an user I am editing so he doesn't need to log-out to have the new details, such as a role for example.

My edit function is:

```
public function edit($id = null)
    {
    if (!$id) {
        $this->Flash->error(__('User not found.'));
    }

    $user = $this->Users->get($id);
    if ($this->request->is(['post', 'put'])) {
        $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
        if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('User has been updated.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'edit/' . $id]);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to update User details.'));
    }

    $this->set(compact('user'));
}
```

How can I accomplish this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
public function edit($id = null)
    {
    if (!$id) {
        $this->Flash->error(__('User not found.'));
    }

    $user = $this->Users->get($id);
    if ($this->request->is(['post', 'put'])) {
        $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
        if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('User has been updated.'));
            $this->request->session()->write([Auth.YourUserVariable => $user]);
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'edit/' . $id]);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to update User details.'));
    }

    $this->set(compact('user'));
```

}

Then when your user uptade his/her profile if it save the user it will overide session, are you using Auth ok? To see details from user you can try this:

```
debug($this->request->session()->read('Auth'));exit;
```

Or something like this ;)

Comment: I want to update other users and refresh their sessions if a database change has been made. This seems to only refresh the session for the user who changes it, instead of that from one other. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Yes this may change just for the user who done that. I already have done something like this. I have a user, user has a group, and a group has many users, a group has many permitions, when I change a a permission  for a group I don't change it in session (because, I dont fixed it in session) I control access by controller action, then when user enter that controller action, application verify if he/her have access to that controller/action if yes ok enter, else redirect to refer page. (Than u don't need to fixed in session) I did it with an API that control all child aplications/users/groups.